# Value of HTML input type button shown twice with PhoneGap

Tags: android, html, button, cordova

I have weird behaviour using regular HTML input type button with phonegap (android/eclipse). This is the HTML that is causing my headache:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<title>PhoneGap</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Rest Call" onClick="restCall(); />
<button type="button" onClick="restCall();">Rest Call</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The result of this is two buttons with the correct label/value, "Rest Call". But, to the left of both buttons the same text is also shown. So the label/value is shown twice.

I have spent some time on this now, not finding a solution. Hope someone can help.

Cheers,
OMA

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is some conflict between the two scripts, I get the same behaviour as mentioned by TDeBailleul.

I am doing some ajax calls etc which needs jQuery-1.x.x.js. All the how-to's on using phonegap with jquery also says to do this.

I found now that I need to use a specific version of jquery mobile (jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js), which is weird. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction TDeBailleul.

Answer (score 4):

I just tried to create a PhoneGap 1.4.1 project with your HTML in it.
I couldn't reproduce the problem until I added :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
```

I thought this was a problem with that specific file but then I remove

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js"></script>
```

and it worked fine.

So I think there is a conflict between these two files.

I'm no jQuery/jQMobile expert but are you sure you need both these files (especially `jQuery-1.7.1.js`) ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change your code to :

```
<input type="button" value="Rest Call" name="hei" onClick="restCall();"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the interest. I now edited the HTML to call the function. My problem is still that the value/text of the buttons is shown twice though :-)